# Conflicts when installing Anaconda Python

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I have recently installed the Anaconda distribution of Python. I then inserted the following line into my `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/Anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

So, there are now two `python` binary files: one in `/usr/bin/`, and one in `/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/Anaconda/bin`.

I also have a python script, which attempts to import a module named `caffe`, with the line `import caffe`. Now, if I run `python caffe` from the terminal, the script runs fine. However, if I open the script in PyCharm, and set the interpreter to be `/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/Anaconda/bin/python`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named caffe
```

Based on all this, I have two questions....

1. If I run the `python` command from the terminal, which binary file would it execute? The one in `/usr/bin`, or the one in `/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/Anaconda/bin`? My intuition is that it runs the first one, due to the discrepancy in behaviour with PyCharm. In that case, how can I force my system to use the Anaconda version?
2. If I install a new package, for example `pip install caffe`, then where will it be installed to? Will it be installed to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, or to `/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/Anaconda/pkgs`? How can I be sure that my `python` command will know where to find the new package?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to 1**:

Based on your example: `export PATH=/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/Anaconda/bin:$PATH` the `/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/Anaconda/bin` comes first, so the python from there should be the one to be executed.

But the definite answer depends on result of running: `which python`.

**Answer to 2**:

In Anaconda, use `conda` instead of `pip` to install packages. When you install using `pip install caffe` you'll be installing to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Use `conda install caffe` to install to `/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/Anaconda/pkgs`.

---

Above two answers explain why even if you `pip install spam` package, `python` would say `ImportError: No module named spam`. Essentially you install to ordinary Python, but you attempt to import in Anaconda's python.