# Pydev import not working, but Terminal import does

Tags: python, anaconda, pydev

I recently installed a library (obspy) on my MBP with anaconda. The installation seemed successful but for some reason I can't get it to run in my Eclipse (PyDev) environment. Going into the python shell on Terminal does however work. How can make the two consistent?

Comment: Is your PyDev installation using Anaconda's python interpreter or the default one?

Comment: I use the Anacaonda interpreter which I've had on there for a year. The "import pandas" shows up with a import not resolved (red line), but still works. Yesterday I made another installation of Anaconda, and I can't seem to get obspy to run. I'm not sure how to configure property in my .profile (.bash_profile), pydev.

Comment: Take a long look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070845/conflicts-when-installing-anaconda-python/38159727#38159727 - basically remember that anaconda is a separate Python installation, with a separate package management. So make sure that package is installed in the right place, and when you run the interpreter, it is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the same Python in both places and the same PYTHONPATH in both cases.

To do that, create a script with:

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))
print(sys.executable)
```

and run from your terminal and from Eclipse to see if you have the same thing in both.